# Rotativa breaks the HTML when there is more than one page

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, rotativa

I am creating a pdf from HTML using Rotativa, and my code looks like this

```
     var CustomSwitches = "--footer-right \"Date: [date] [time]\" " + "--footer-center \"Page: [page] of [toPage]\" --footer-line --footer-font-size \"9\" --footer-spacing 5 --footer-font-name \"calibri light\"";

    var rotativaOptions = new DriverOptions { CustomSwitches = CustomSwitches,PageSize = Size.A4};

    return new ViewAsPdf("~/Views/Partials/Report/SummaryReportspdf.cshtml")
    {
        RotativaOptions = rotativaOptions
    };
```

All looks good to me, but when there is more than one page, page breaks even. And it looks like below image
[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem using the latest version of wkhtmltopdf (currently version 0.12.5)

You can download it from here: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Syncfusion [HTML to PDF converter in C#](https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net/html-to-pdf) provides an option to convert HTML to PDF without text and image split across the pages. Refer the help documentation for more information

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/webkit#split-text

Note: I work for Syncfusion.